# How do you create a custom attribute store in ADFS 4.0?

Tags: adfs

I'm trying to create a custom attribute in ADFS 4.0 running on Windows Server 2016 and I've been following this guide: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/cloudpfe/2013/12/27/how-to-create-a-custom-attribute-store-for-active-directory-federation-services-3-0/

- I'm targeting .NET Framework 4.5 (which the OS has in-built).
- I've copied the exact `Microsoft.IdentityServer.ClaimsPolicy.dll` file from the ADFS server and referenced it in my project.
- The only other library I've referenced is the `System.IdentityModel`.

When attempting to add the custom attribute store I've created to ADFS after copying the built library across into the `C:\Windows\ADFS` folder I receive an error in the event log:

> During processing of the Federation Service configuration, the attribute store 'ClassLibrary1' could not be loaded.
> Attribute store type: ClassLibrary1.Basic, Basic
>
> User Action
> If you are using a custom attribute store, verify that the custom attribute store is configured using AD FS Management snap-in.
>
> Additional Data
> Could not load file or assembly 'Basic' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

What could be causing the above error?

Does anyone have any working guides/tutorials/examples of how to create a full end-to-end custom attribute store in ADFS 4.0?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Whoops... Turns out that when adding the custom attribute store in ADFS itself I was adding the namespace of `ClassLibrary1.Basic,Basic` instead of `ClassLibrary1.Basic,ClassLibrary1`.